# Почему два div не выровневаются при точных значений координат?

Tags: html, css

Элемент div с идентификатором "#block2" слегка ниже чем элемент div с идентификатором "#block1"...

```css
#block1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
}

#block2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 104px;
  margin-top: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="block1"></div>
<div id="block2"></div>
```

Почему так происходит ?

Comment: Элементы div не выровневаются, потому что значение отступа вверху margin-top: -100px для элемента #block2 указано как отрицательное. Чтобы выровнять либо измени, либо удали

Comment: margin-top: -100px; из-за этой строчки

Comment: display: inline-block помогло. спасибо!

Comment: неровно получалось потому что вы не учитывали border по 1px сверху и снизу - поэтому -102px идеально бы подошло.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Странно, что столько людей сказали про `102px`, но никто не сказал откуда берутся эти `2px`..

Всё дело в `border: 1px`, из-за того, что есть свойство [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing), которое по дефолту имеет значение `content-box`, `border` будет добавлять ещё и своё значение размера к основному.

Именно так получается, что фактически ваш блок равен следующим размерам:

```
width  = border-left-width + width + border-right-width  = 1px + 100px + 1px = 102px
height = border-top-width + height + border-bottom-width = 1px + 100px + 1px = 102px
```

По этому чтобы расположить блок `#block2` на том же уровне, что и `block1`, вам потребуется указать `margin-top: -102px`.

```css
#block1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
}

#block2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 104px;
  margin-top: -102px;
}
```

```html
<div id="block1"></div>
<div id="block2"></div>
```

Или указать значение для блоков `box-sizing: border-box`, тогда размеры `border` будут "съедаться вовнутрь", тем самым блок всегда будет того размера, которого вы указали.

```css
#block1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
}

#block2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 104px;
  margin-top: -102px;
}
```

```html
<div id="block1"></div>
<div id="block2"></div>
```

---

А вообще не понятно зачем такое извращение, чтобы расположить элементы горизонтально, давно используют [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

```css
#block1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#block2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: 104px;
  margin-top: -100px;
  animation: BorderWidth 1s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes BorderWidth {
  to {border-width: 15px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="block1"></div>
<div id="block2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Из-за строчки margin-top, удалите этот параметр, либо поставь 102,104px

Answer (score 0):

Потому что у тебя высота блоков не 100, а 102. Наверное, ты хотел вот так:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#block1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
}

#block2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 104px;
  margin-top: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="block1"></div>
<div id="block2"></div>
```

PS: А вообще, ты что-то странное делаешь.